# Chrome Update causes Blank Pop-ups

Tags: google-chrome, updates, version

**What changes in recent updates to *Chrome* might have caused my pop-ups to not render correctly?  Are there any work-arounds?**

Recently, popups within a web application that I am a developer for stopped working after updating to the latest version of *Chrome* (61.0.3163.79, from something in the 60.x range).  The modal dialog boxes, which previously had various controls in them, now render as blank.  The page still works properly in *Firefox.*

[image: Before and After]

It may be that the update caused a legitimate increase in code strictness, and that our app should be debugged and revised; however, **that is not on topic on this site** (I may ask that as a separate question on Stack Overflow).  Rather, my question here is **whether this is a commonly-seen or known issue relating to an update of *Chrome* in the 60.x or 61.x line of versions.**

Comment: Did u updated Java? Tried

Comment: @TechieGossip I tend to actively avoid updating Java for fear that doing so will break other aspects of my development work.